# How do I select a key/value pair by finding the smallest value in a number of key/value pairs in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
  thingA: 5,
  thingB: 10,
  thingC: 15
}
```

I would like to be able to select the key/value pair `thingA: 5` based on the fact that 5 is the smallest value compared to the other key/value pairs.

Comment: Loop through the keys, and compare the values (keep track of the lowest value)?

Comment: What about the case where different "keys" have the same smallest value? Let's say `thingD : 5` for instance. Is it possible? In that case, what should be the expected result?

Comment: @ZER0 Good question! In this case it doesn't matter; any result key will do if it has the smallest value.

Comment: In that case one of the @minitech answers is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built-in does that, but:

```
var minPair = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    return [k, obj[k]];
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] < a[1] ? b : a;
});

minPair // ['thingA', 5]
```

Or, sans ECMAScript 5 extensions:

```
var minKey, minValue;

for(var x in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        if(!minKey || obj[x] < minValue) {
            minValue = obj[x];
            minKey = x;
        }
    }
}

[minKey, minValue] // ['thingA', 5]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never really used the map.reduce pattern before so I am going to take some time to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple function that can do exactly what you wanted -

```
function getSmallest(obj)
{
    var min,key;
    for(var k in obj)
    {
        if(typeof(min)=='undefined')
        {
            min=obj[k];
            key=k;
            continue;
        }
        if(obj[k]<min)
        {
            min=obj[k]; 
            key=k;
        }
    }
    return key+':'+min;
}



//test run
var obj={thingA:5,thingB:10,thingC:15};
var smallest=getSmallest(obj)//thingA:5
```